# How to late bound WPF ComboBox using ObjectDataProvider

Tags: wpf, combobox

Suppose we have a WPF ComboBox and want to populate it using ObjectDataProvider.

```
<ObjectDataProvider ObjectType="{x:Type provider:DataProviderProxy}" x:Key="BLDataProvider">
 </ObjectDataProvider>
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="InstallDriverProvider" 
                  ObjectInstance="{StaticResource BLDataProvider}"
                 MethodName="GetInstallDrivers" 
                 IsAsynchronous="True">
</ObjectDataProvider>


<ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" 
          IsEditable="False"
          AlternationCount="2"
          IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource InstallDriverProvider}}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=InstallDriverPlugin, Mode=TwoWay}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding Path=InstallDriverPlugin.Name, Mode=TwoWay}"
          SelectedValuePath="id"
        ...
```

If the GetInstallDrivers() method calls some server method that returns asynchronously like a response from web service how it would be possible to populate the combobox?
How to populate the combobox after the response has arrived?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to populate the combo box asynchronously, then it's not the best idea to use ObjectDataProvider. But instead use a ViewModel (and the MVVM pattern), which has the combobox datasource as an observable collection member property. Then simply get the data asyncrhrounously, then post it to the UI thread and fill the collection.

Comment: I agree it is not the best idea but I wanted to use ObjectDataProvider because I reused a code that talks to the database so every call returned almost immediately. When I changed from db to server using NamedPipes I had to implement some request/response communication to keep original code unchanged. See my trick.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution that works. Maybe it is not the best but it works and the maintenance is focused to one place on the DataProvider.

I used multibinding, MultiValueConverter, DataObjectProvider.
Firstly I extended and implemented  my proxy class with **INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging**. After that I added a property to contain the result and after that changed the XAML.

```
public class DataProviderProxy : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging
{
    private BusinessLayer BL;

    private List<Transfer.InstallDriverPlugin> _InstallDrivers = new List<Transfer.InstallDriverPlugin>();
    public List<Transfer.InstallDriverPlugin> InstallDrivers
    {
        get
        {
            return _InstallDrivers;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_InstallDrivers != value)
            {
                RaisePropertyChanging("InstallDrivers");
                _InstallDrivers = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("InstallDrivers");
            }
        }
    }
```

... then I placed a common method to send a request to a server and retrieve the data

```
    public List<Transfer.InstallDriverPlugin> GetInstallDrivers()
    {
        RequestContext rq = App.BL.GetInstallPlugins("DATA_PROVIDER_InstallDrivers");
        App.BL.Admin.SetRequestCustomData(rq, new object[] { });
        return InstallDrivers;
    }
```

... the method to process the response from the Server

```
    public void ProcessResponse(ResponseContext rc)
    {
        // Response filter

        ...

        #region Parse result by command
        switch (rc.Command)
        {
            case AgentCommands.GetInstallPlugins:
                if (rc.UserToken == "DATA_PROVIDER_InstallDrivers")
                {
                    App.BL.Admin.ConsumeRequest(rc);
                    InstallDrivers = (List<Transfer.InstallDriverPlugin>)rc.result;
                }
                break;
```

... in the XAML

```
      <ObjectDataProvider ObjectType="{x:Type provider:DataProviderProxy}" x:Key="BLDataProvider">
        </ObjectDataProvider>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="InstallDriverProvider" 
                ObjectInstance="{StaticResource BLDataProvider}"
                MethodName="GetInstallDrivers"
                IsAsynchronous="True">
        </ObjectDataProvider>

        <ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" 
                  IsEditable="False"
                  AlternationCount="2"
                  IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
                  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                  DataContext="{StaticResource BLDataProvider}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=InstallDriverPlugin, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  SelectedValue="{Binding Path=InstallDriverPlugin.Name, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  SelectedValuePath="id"
                  Background="LightGreen"
                  MinHeight="29"
                  KeyDown="ComboBoxKeyDownHandler"
                  SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged">
          <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource InstDrvConverter}">
                    <Binding Source="{StaticResource InstallDriverProvider}"/>
                    <Binding Path="InstallDrivers" Source="{StaticResource BLDataProvider}"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        </ComboBox>
```

The first binding calls the metod to retrieve the date that asynchronously returns the result and fills the property. The Second binding binds the combobox to the property **InstallDrivers**. 
Finally the multi value converter takes always the value from the second binding, the Property.

```
public class InstallDriverConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    #region IMultiValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            return values[1];
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I know it is more ore less complicated but has several advantages. Almost everything is in XAML, administration is centralized, and if you have developed a form and wanted to fill similar data you can cut & paste the code and reuse it simply making a little customization in XAML.